# Cocoa: Do I need to initialize value transformers for use in IB?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsvaluetransformer

I have two custom value transformers contained within my "Other Sources" folder, bound to table columns in IB, which I initialize thusly:

```
@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialization code
        [self initialiseValueTransformers];
    }

return self;
```

}

```
- (void) initialiseValueTransformers {
    MyFirstTransformer *myFirstTransformer = [[[MyFirstTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:myFirstTransformer forName:@"MyFirstTransformer"];

    MySecondTransformer *mySecondTransformer = [[[MySecondTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:mySecondTransformer forName:@"MySecondTransformer"];
}
```

And these work fine in IB with a column bound to arrangedObjects, model key path, value transformer.

**My question is,** I have just written a third transformer, but not initialized it in any way, I just have a the files MyThirdTransformer.h / .m. And it still works in IB..??

Why is this, and do I need to bother initializing the first two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create your own instance of `NSValueTransformer` when used with Cocoa bindings that you make in IB.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought from my problem. So to clarify, for use with IB bindings Transformers need only be described (ie .h and .m). But if I wanted to use them in the code somewhere I would (obviously) need to create an instance(s) of them. Correct?

Comment: You are correct.  The typical use in code would be the programmatic creation of bindings.  In this use case, you would register your `NSValueTransformer` subclass because the `NSValueTransformer` class maintains a mapping of transformer names and the corresponding `NSValueTransformer` object.  See the Value Transformer Programming Guide in the docs.